# Application restart after taking picture with camera(Titanium android)

Tags: android, android-camera, titanium-mobile, android-imageview

I am developing android application, In my application I want to take photo from camera and set as image in image view. my code looks like

```
var img_view = Titanium.UI.createImageView({ 
    image: '/images/default.png',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
}); win.add(img_view);
photo_camera_view = Ti.UI.createView(
{
    height: '20dp',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
}); win.add(photo_camera_view); 
photo_camera_view.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    Titanium.Media.showCamera(
    {
        success:function(event)
        {
            img_view.image =  event.media; 
        },
        cancel:function()
        {
        },
        error:function(error)
        {
            // create alert
        },

    });
});
```

my need is take a pic from camera and set image: 'photo from camera' in img_view. In Android, when I execute Ti.Media.showCamera, after successfully taking a picture and hitting "OK" in the app, the application will restart. I am using titanium sdk 2.0.1 and testing it on android device with android version 2.2. Need Help ..... Thank you........

Comment: @nilcash Did you solve this issue? I'm having this on Android 4.3 and 4.4. I'm using a bare minimum of code to take pictures and then display them in ImageView elements. More often than not the app crashes after tapping the "OK" button from the device camera as you described above. The interesting part is that in case of a crash none of the callback function even gets called (tested with console/alert outputs). Reproducible on Moto G (2nd Gen 2014; 4.4) and Samsung Galaxy S3 (4.3). May be a memory issue as it works better after a fresh restart but then happens again after some uptime.

Comment: @PhilippRieber I already raise ticket for this problem. According to titanium team replay they are not able to reproduce this problem. But this problem was long back about 2 years back. I am not sure whether you are facing same problem or it may be something else.

Comment: @nilcash I've refreshed a report about this issue in Jira and it was re-opened now: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-12848
Yes, it seems they are not able to reproduce it; but I can reproduce it all the time on two different devices, even after a factory reset and with no other apps installed. Did you find any workaround for it? The only purpose of my app is to take photos so it's quite a showstopper.

Comment: @PhilippRieber I am really sorry because at this point I am not able to help you. I left working on titanium 2 years back so I totally unaware about what's these guys are doing now. May be you can raise one more ticket so that these guys can focus on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the image in the success event like below.

```
img_view.setImage(event.media);
```

You just cannot assign the image to the property. The image view has to be redrawn with new image. And try it in Android 4.0 emulator as the below versions had issues with camera.